# Iteratively UPDATE column with foreign column

Tags: postgresql

I have the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE results (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  map_id UUID,
  -- other irrelevant columns
);

CREATE TABLE mapping (
  client_id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  server_id UUID UNIQUE
)
```

As part of an ETL cleanup step, the task is to go through all entries in `mapping` and update `results` by swapping all `client_id` matches against `server_id`. After this, no `map_id` in `results` may be a `client_id`.

Currently, my naive approach is to use the calling language (C#) to iterate through all the records in `mapping` and perform an

```
UPDATE results
SET map_id = @server_id
WHERE map_id = @client_id
```

However, this can probably be optimized. Reading through related questions, loops are highly discouraged in SQL. So how can I express my iterative approach above as a SQL statement? I'm using Postgres 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE results
SET map_id = (SELECT server_id 
              FROM mapping m 
              WHERE m.client_id = results.map_id)
WHERE map_id IN (SELECT client_id FROM mapping);
```

Another approach:

```
UPDATE results AS r
SET map_id = m.server_id
FROM mapping m
WHERE m.client_id = r.map_id
```

Comment: I forgot to mention this, but `mapping` might not have a mapping for all ids in `results`. Additionally, Some results might already have their "proper id". Will this still work? I guess the subquery will be empty in that case.

Comment: @mınxomaτ `I forgot to mention this, but mapping might not have a mapping for all ids in results.` That is why you have `WHERE` part.

Comment: `m.map_id = results.client_id` is flipped ;)

Comment: @mınxomaτ Sure, fixed